# ggplot: create relative stacked histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I managed to create a nice histogram from my data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Score)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = factor(Answer, levels=c("5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "NULL")))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,250)) +
  labs(x = "Score", y = "Count", fill="Answer")
```

Yields:
[image]

What I really want to know, however, is the relative frequency of each answer within each bin, not the absolute number. That is, I want each bin to be of height 1, with fills representing the proportion of that answer within that bin.

I'm cautiously optimistic that this is probably easy to do, but I just don't know how. I'd appreciate any help the community could offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can really call it a histogram anymore, but using `position = "fill"` does this. Using an example with built-in data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_histogram(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I wanted!